# Автоматически сменить роль пользователя, если он переходит по ссылке

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Есть сайт на WordPress. Есть роль пользователя `block1_course2`, которую нужно присвоить пользователю, в тот момент, когда он кликнет на ссылку "`site.com/courses/kurs-2-2/`". Можно ли такое реализовать? Читала про `add_role()`, но не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать так

1. Вариант с переходом на страницу

```
add_action('wp', 'add_new_role', 10, 2);

function add_new_role() {
    
       global $wp;
       
       $current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
       
       if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_slug == 'courses/kurs-2-2') {
                
                $u = new WP_User( get_current_user_id() );

                $u->set_role( 'new_role' );
       }
}
```

2. Вариант с кликом

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       
        $("a[href='https://site.com/courses/kurs-2-2/']").click(function(){
            
                         jQuery.ajax({
                             url: '<?php admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                             type: 'GET',
                             data: 'action=set_user_role', 
                             success: function( data ) {
                   
                             }
                        });
            
                        return false;
            
        }); 
    });
```

```
    add_action('wp_ajax_set_user_role', 'set_user_role');
    
    function set_user_role() {
        
         $u = new WP_User( get_current_user_id() );

         $u->set_role( 'new_role' );
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает. И в вопросе присвоить роль, а не добавить.

Comment: @АннаМатвеева изменил ответ. метод set_role https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/set_role/

Comment: Работает. Но я так поняла, что при переходе на страницу courses/kurs-2-2/, а не при клике на ссылку?

Comment: @АннаМатвеева добавил еще вариант с кликом

Comment: Теперь ни при клике, ни при переходе не добавляется роль ((

Comment: @АннаМатвеева менялся только способ вызова. смотрите логи

Comment: А если я вставляю в адресную строку site.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php и на странице отображается просто "0". Это норм? Может у меня не работает admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );

Comment: @АннаМатвеева  ответ 0 правильно . Чтоб что-то другое выводилось - нужно выводить в функции set_user_role() ответ.  Сама смена роли происходит ?

Comment: Нет. Когда по клику начали делать, перестала роль меняться.

Comment: Только что попробовала другим пользователем. И получилось. А предыдущим пользователем не хотело. Наверное то, что я просто права для пользователя откатила, что то значит...

Comment: Странно даже то, что удалила пользователя, потом создала нового и все ровно не хочет меняться роль. Как будто только один раз можно менять, а откатывать нельзя назад через админку - нельзя.

Comment: @АннаМатвеева вызов set_user_role() происходит?

Comment: А как это посмотреть? Где эти логи?

Comment: @АннаМатвеева в функции в самой где-нибудь внизу вывести что-нибудь

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать...

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли такое реализовать? Читала про add_role(), но не могу
> разобраться.

`add_role()` используется для **создания** роли. Для **присваивания** роли юзеру нужно использовать хук `add_user_role()`

Comment: Не могли бы пример написать. Пробовала сделать по аналогии с ответом выше, но ни к чему не привело.